# Does FlashDevelop have a feature changing a value when I'm debugging?

Tags: flashdevelop

Does FlashDevelop have a feature changing a value when I'm debugging?
If so, how do i change a value?

To explain more detail for the feature above,
I want you to see the example of the same feature in VisualStudio.
Please look at chapter 4. "4. Modify Any Variable" in the site:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/visual_studio_tips.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Immediate Panel, that act's like a console for actionscript code

set a breakpoint and use following syntax:

```
p variable="value"
```

Comment: In FlashDevelop 4.3.0, I need to write `p variable=value` (that is, no initial forward slash) for it to work.